# How to use KnexJS for multiple Databases using env file?

Tags: knex.js

I have two databases and I wish to use both in my backend. I have few queries for db1 and few for db2. now, I have knexconfig file in which I am giving the configuration from env file. How can I give two db configuration to that so that it works with db1 when required and with db2 when required.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is configure a second connection and export a knex instance for each:

```
const db1_connection = {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB1_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB1_USER,
    password: process.env.DB1_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB1_DATABASE,
  },
}

const db2_connection = {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB2_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB2_USER,
    password: process.env.DB2_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB2_DATABASE,
  },
}

export const knexDB1 = Knex(db1_connection)
export const knexDB2 = Knex(db2_connection)
```

then in your code you can get values from different dbs like this:

```
const db1_users = await knexDB1.table("users").select('id', 'name')
const db2_users = await knexDB2.table("users").select('id', 'name')
```